# Drupal 6 Active Menu Items for all nodes of a type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have my primary links. I have a menu item called Albums. It has the path */albums*. I have an *album* content type. If I create a node of that type it automatically gets the URL */albums/*. The node has not been assigned a place in the menu but I wish the Albums menu entry to be set as active. How can I do this? I don't really want to set the menu item for each node that I create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most things there is a module to do it: [Auto Menu](http://drupal.org/project/automenu).

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I think if you do not want to create menu item for each node created, better use [the context module](http://drupal.org/project/context)